# Overload Operator<< for a derived class of a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism, operator-overloading

***Some bits of context :*** I am writing a serialization library, and want to keep to a minimum the needed changes for the objects I want to serialize. I found some great examples, such as [MetaStuff](https://github.com/eliasdaler/MetaStuff), but would like to implement it myself for template practice and customization.

**My problem :**

I want to overload operator<< for my derived classes.
The derived classes inherit from a Base class which is a specialized template to themselves (via CRTP).
So far, member variable I want to output are public, so let's leave aside the need to declare friend the operator.

```
template<typename Class>
Class Base {

protected:
    Base(std::string name) : name(name){}

public:
    const std::string name;

    static int f(const Class& instance){
        return instance.a;
    }
};
```

(i simplified a lot to keep only essential elements)

```
struct Derived : public Base<Derived>{

    Derived():Base<Derived>("Derived"){}

    int a;

    static bool registerClass(){ return true; //called by Base<Derived> }
};
```

I am running into 3 conflicting issues (depending on the solution i give a try) :

**Issue 1: ambiguous template resolution**

```
template <typename Class>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Class& obj)
{
    os << obj.name << "[ ";
    os << Base<Class>::f(obj);
    os << "]";

    return os;
};
```

Here I run into the ambiguous overload issue. The template function has exact same prototype as the generic one.
[Code & Compile error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b3ba0b0dad3534)

**Issue 2 : Type Slicing**

```
template <typename Class>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base<Class>& obj)
{
    os << obj.name << "[ ";
    os << Base<Class>::f(obj); 
    //will not compile, since obj is not a Class object anymore.
    os << "]";

    return os;
};
```

As stated in the comment, object is sliced when passed to the function and I can't pass it then as argument to the static Base function f.
[Code & Compile error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735fb03af15a9b5f)

**Issue 3 : Function Template Specialization is incorrect**

Partial specialization of template function is not possible, and overall function template specialization is to be avoided : compiler will always prefer Base template. (see this nice [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm))

**What is left ?**

I am thinking about using solution 2 with static_cast but feel it would be ugly ? I gave a try to a few other solution, which were not worth mentioning.

Has anyone more clues ?

(Since i want modifications to Derived classes to be minimal, i don't want to add a virtual function or so on)

Comment: where is the slicing in 2? Afaik, references dont slice only values do

Comment: you want to have a single implementation for any `Derived`?

Comment: "//will not compile, since obj is not a Class object anymore." of course the object is still of type `Class`, the only reason is see this wont compile is that the `operator<<` takes a `obj` as a const reference while `Base<Class>::f(obj);` expects a non-const. If you fix that I dont see the problem

Comment: Sorry someone edited "inherit from a Base class via CRTP" while i was editting myself, so i overwrote it. I replaced his comment since. Interesting I didn't know this was a named pattern, i will search on this keyword then ;)

Comment: sorry the const dropped when i wrote the code on so, let me fix.

Comment: now i dont see why 2 does not compile. You should provide a [mcve] and the error messages you get....or wait for someone more clever to see what I am missing, though I am pretty sure 2 is just fine

Comment: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Base<Derived>’ to ‘const Derived&’

Comment: the error message alone doesnt help, we need to see the code that causes the error. What you show is only the templates not how you use them

Comment: What is `f` supposed to return? [Here's a proper implementation of that operator that resolves `f` properly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ca18bb8f2416bba), but it doesn't fix `f` being kinda ambiguous itself.

Comment: Yes f is actually more than 1 function which provides iterators to a map of other template classes. I prefered to simplify to keep it minimal. Your proposition looks quite promising, i had thought about using enable_if but was not sure about the syntax. I had to adapt it to C++11 since my cross compiler is not supporting beyond

Comment: With a more concrete f function : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/318952e05bbb23a2

Comment: and to answer to @user463035818 : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/735fb03af15a9b5f this won't work.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : Could you post your answer so I could accept it. I would be also interested for a brief explanation or a link why compilers manage to solve the ambiguous overload, thanks to the enable_if ?

Comment: Added links to coliru viewer with code and compile error. The ones i shared within the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution is a mix of code in your attempts 1 and 2.

```
template <
    typename Class,
    typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<Base<Class>, Class>::value >::type
>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Class& obj)
{
    os << obj.name << "[ ";
    os << Base<Class>::f(obj);
    os << " ]";

    return os;
}
```

- You need to take `Class&` and not `Base<Class>&`, because you (might)want to operate on the members of `Class`.
- However, `enable_if` is used so that the operator only works for types that are derived from `Base`; this prevents it creeping into other overloads (in general, overloads and templates mix poorly), as such a template overload could potentially match anything.
- We also explicitly need to pass the `Class` to the `Base` to get the proper `f`.

---

Also, a small note; with a modern compiler, you can spell it a bit more nicely:

```
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base<Class>, Class>>
```

Comment: 1) ok and 3) was a typo in the question. For point 2) i understand that the compiler will solve template first with the ones with 'enable_if' (SFINAE) ? Correct ?

Comment: @Pellekrino Yes, this is SFINAE; the way this works is simply that for types other than the ones derived from Base, it will produce a type that will break that template, removing it from potential candidate set. You can read about `enable_if` specifically elsewhere, there's tons of materials on the web.

Comment: understood that it will break compilation for other types. my question is rather about the fact there was already the template prototype "template <typename Class>std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Class& obj);" available. So now we have provided this prototype : template <typename Class, typename = Void>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Class& obj);

Comment: Better to use `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0` than `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`. that would allow other overloads.

Comment: enable_if_t is a helper only available with C++14.

Answer (score 1):

[CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) generally uses `static_cast`:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    explicit Base(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)){}

    const T& asDerived() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this); }
    T& asDerived() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }

public:
    const std::string name;

    static int f(const Base<T>& instance){
        return instance.asDerived().a;
    }
};
```

And so

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base<T>& obj)
{
    os << obj.name << "[ ";
    os << Base<T>::f(obj);
    os << "]";

    return os;
}
```

Note that `Base::f` would no longer need to be `static`:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    // ...
    int f() const { return asDerived().a; }
    // ...
};
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base<T>& obj)
{
    return os << obj.name << "[ " << obj.f() << "]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the static_cast was also a good way to go. I was reading about static polymorpĥism just now ;)